# trying to scan in to a 2-d malloc'd array c programming

Tags: c

i've looked through quite a few questions of 2-d malloc'd arrays already but bascially for whatever reason i cannot find a solution.... my google fu sux sorry =(. been using the site all day for syntactual help though thanks to everyone who helps here! =)

anyways i cant seem to get this fscanf to work =/ if someone could help me it would be much appreciated because i cant see any error at all but i know there is one because it is at this point that my program crashes.

```
    array1 = (int**)malloc((c)*sizeof(int*));
        int a = 0, i = 0;
        for (a = 0; a < c; a++){
            array1[a] = (int*)malloc((c+1)*sizeof(int));

        }
    a=0;

    for(a = 0; a < c; a++){
                for(i = 0; i < c; i++){
                fscanf(ifp, "%d", array1[a][i]);

    }
    }
```

where c is the maximum size of the array needed. in this case it is set to 3 but i do need it as a variable

Comment: "I've looked through quite a few questions" - [Not enough.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 5):

When using the `scanf` family of function to read a value, the destination needs to be a pointer. `array1[a][i]` is *not* a pointer, it an actual value (which `scanf` will treat as a pointer and you now entered the territory of *undefined behavior*).

What you want is `&array1[a][i]`.

PS.
You should not cast the returned value of `malloc`.

Comment: ok i definitely missed out on something conceptual then. i thought the array[i][j] syntax is a pointer for a said address hence the i,j. does it work differently for strings when scanning in then? because my scanning in for strings didnt require an & (ie: address)

Comment: @user2053368 A string already is an pointer, so the address-of operator is not needed there. If you have a pointer `p` and an index `i` then the expression `p[i]` is the _value_ at that index, and to get the address to that value (i.e. the pointer) you use the address-of operator `&` as in `&p[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

fscanf takes pointers, so I would think you need to prepend its third argument with an ampersand.  Didn't the compiler warn you about that?

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array1[a][i]);
                  ^
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It wouldn't be a bad idea to give a little more explanation of why the change you suggest is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

malloc and other syntext is correct, the issue is in reading the value to array

replace this 
`fscanf(ifp, "%d", array1[a][i]);`

with

`fscanf(ifp, "%d", &array1[a][i]);`

Always enable complier warning, and pay heed to it:)

Answer (score 0):

[You need to read this.](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?scanf%203)

Please develop habit of reading manpages. It helps a lot.

Comment: whoa never seen that before... thanks for the headsup ill take a look at it right now